# Is it possible to call javascript function to the pageload event in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, events

Suppose i have created one .js file name as: MyNoteBook.js. In this .js file i have written function as name count(). 
Now I am creating MyNoteBook.aspx page in asp.net. On the event of pageload of .aspx file, i want to call that count() function of that .js file. Is it is possible, If yes  then please tell me.

If no, then how i can write count function in .aspx page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call a JS function on page load, make sure there is an `onLoad` attribute on the `body` tag that calls it:

```
<body onLoad="count();">
```

This all happens *client side*, as Javascript runs in the browser.

You can't call a client side function from server side code.

---

As for writing the function server side - without knowing what it does, no one can tell you how to convert it to server side code.

Comment: Ok sir , I am writing the next question through which, you can know what i want to do in aspx page.

Answer (score 1):

you could use ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

have a look at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use the javascript pageLoad function from the ASP.NET Ajax framework. You can find more information about the ajax client-side life-cycle events [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386417.aspx).